# Scraping text between pseudo elements

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl an auction website(https://onlineonly.christies.com/s/first-open-post-war-contemporary-art/massimo-vitali-b-1944-203/43092). I want to use css.selector to select the price of the painting with python scrapy. I am unable to use selector to select the text element between ::before and ::after pseudo-elements.

I have looked at the raw HTML and there is no price indicated in the raw format of the website.

```py
response.css("div.price-realised.row:before").get() #This does not work
```

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

That price is coming from a XHR:
https://onlineonly.christies.com/lot/43092/reloadbiddetails?saleType=Esf&isInLead=False

You can search from the network panel when you're not sure which response the data is in.

Comment: Can we use CSS selector to access that data? Is it different from XHR?

Comment: The XHR is json so you just parse it with json.loads